# what should I add in the OnPressed in flutter to do the google OAuth sign in?

Tags: flutter

this is the code, I've already done everything, but I'm stuck on the OnPressed and don't know what to do.
please help,

`SignInButton(Buttons.Google, onPressed:  .... )`

I'm trying to do google sign in on a mobile application for a class project, but I'm unable to figure it out, I've done the facebook one but google is just a pain.. lol,
please help

Comment: You can check this url https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example  make sure. Perform all the given steps in readme tab first.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies:
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.3
```

Example:

---

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;

import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  // Optional clientId
  // clientId: '479882132969-9i9aqik3jfjd7qhci1nqf0bm2g71rm1u.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;
  String _contactText = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleGetContact(_currentUser!);
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<void> _handleGetContact(GoogleSignInAccount user) async {
    setState(() {
      _contactText = "Loading contact info...";
    });
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
          '?requestMask.includeField=person.names'),
      headers: await user.authHeaders,
    );
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      setState(() {
        _contactText = "People API gave a ${response.statusCode} "
            "response. Check logs for details.";
      });
      print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
      return;
    }
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
    final String? namedContact = _pickFirstNamedContact(data);
    setState(() {
      if (namedContact != null) {
        _contactText = "I see you know $namedContact!";
      } else {
        _contactText = "No contacts to display.";
      }
    });
  }

  String? _pickFirstNamedContact(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<dynamic>? connections = data['connections'];
    final Map<String, dynamic>? contact = connections?.firstWhere(
      (dynamic contact) => contact['names'] != null,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    if (contact != null) {
      final Map<String, dynamic>? name = contact['names'].firstWhere(
        (dynamic name) => name['displayName'] != null,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (name != null) {
        return name['displayName'];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();

  Widget _buildBody() {
    GoogleSignInAccount? user = _currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: user,
            ),
            title: Text(user.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(user.email),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          Text(_contactText),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('REFRESH'),
            onPressed: () => _handleGetContact(user),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text("You are not currently signed in."),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
            onPressed: _handleSignIn,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }
}
```